# Get non-standard user attributes in layout

Tags: 7, users, theming

I want to show the amount of credits the user has. I know the $user object has the following properties:

```
uid - name - pass - mail - theme - signature - signature_format - created - access - login - status - timezone - language - picture - init - data - sid - ssid - hostname - timestamp - cache - session - roles
```

But I have also extended user properties like `address street, address city, user credits, ...` . But how can I print those properties in my layout theme? They are also not in my users table in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`user_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7) to load all additional fields.

E.g.

```
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
$street = $account->field_address_street[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to access the additional user fields you will need to load the full user object using an available user id with the [user_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/7)() function.

```
global $user; //This contains the basic information for your current user.  

$account = user_load($user->uid); //$account now includes all of your custom account fields.
```

Now that you have the fully loaded user object you will need to choose a template to modify.

Depending on where the values need to be, this could be one of many templates.  I highly recommend checking out the [Theme Developer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to help find preprocessing functions and available templates to override.

There is some fantastic information on [setting up variables for use in a template](https://drupal.org/node/223430) here.

Example snip:

```
<?php
function drop_preprocess_foo(&$variables) {
  // Do not do this unless you mean to:
  $variables['foo_list'] = array('list item 4');
  // Instead do this:
  $variables['foo_list'][] = 'list item 4';
}
?>
```